# How to launch Camera app from my windows phone app?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I am trying to launch the built in camera app from within my custom windows phone app to allow the user to capture a photo, save it to disk and then return back to my app to process this new captured image.

The problem is that "[CameraCaptureUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureui.aspx)" is not supported on windows phone! Any work around for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the MediaCapture interface instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx

Comment: I've already tried that but, it doesn't open the Camera App, it just snaps a photo of whatever the camera is pointing at and stores it on disk. I need to open the Camera APP and not just snap a photo without informing the user about it.

Comment: I see, so you want the CameraCaptureTask really correct?